# Prove that if $a \leq b$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f = - \int_{b}^{a} f$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was thinking that since $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f$, I could then say $\int_{a}^{a} f = \int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{b}^{a} f = 0$, so $\int_{a}^{b} f = - \int_{b}^{a} f$.  Is this okay to do?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it's no less obvious that your formulas hold than the thing you want to prove.... Again, these all are simple corollaries from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine, though it is better to put it this way:

$\int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{b}^{a} f = \int_{a}^{a} f = 0$.

Since it is the actual sequence of equalities that you are using.

Comment: And it is totally irrelevant that $a \le b$.

Comment: Doesn't the definition of the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f$ presume $a<b$ and then  *define* (rather than prove) $\int_a^a f = 0$ and  $\int_a^b f = - \int_b^a f$? The reason I'm having difficulty understanding your proof is that the assertion $\int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{b}^{a} f = \int_{a}^{a} f = 0$ presumes that the formula $\int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{b} f$ holds when one of the integrals on the left hand side has an upper limit less than its lower limit. However, one needs to define what it means for an integral to have an upper limit less than its lower limit first

Comment: (cont.) But that definition, then, is precisely what we are trying to prove.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: You can check that the definition of the Riemann integral works even for the 'backward' case, because the little bits involve a negative difference in partition points. Moreover, it is possible to define signed area axiomatically and similarly axiomatize what we wish integrals to behave like. Of course, whether such an axiomatization has an actual model satisfying it is a somewhat secondary question, which can be settled by showing that the Riemann integral does. But it is useful to prove theorems using only the axiomatization, because it generalizes to other models.